# Python and Sharepoint2013

Tags: javascript, python, google-analytics, sharepoint-2013

Please bear with me as i have no prior knowledge of Python and im simply a Network Administrator trying to get the Companies Google Analytics stats to show on our sharepoint homepage.

Im trying to follow the instructions here https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/server-side-authorization/

I have got to step 3 at the point where i need to generate an access token using the following code:

```
# service-account.py

import json
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

# The scope for the OAuth2 request.
SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'

# The location of the key file with the key data.
KEY_FILEPATH = 'path/to/json-key.json'

# Load the key file's private data.
with open(KEY_FILEPATH) as key_file:
  _key_data = json.load(key_file)

# Construct a credentials objects from the key data and OAuth2 scope.
_credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
    _key_data['client_email'], _key_data['private_key'], SCOPE)

# Defines a method to get an access token from the credentials object.
# The access token is automatically refreshed if it has expired.
def get_access_token():
  return _credentials.get_access_token().access_token
```

My question is, Im not 100% sure how im supposed to run/use the above code. Am i supposed to be able to see the requested token and copy paste it into my Javascript, or does it handle this in the background somewhere?

Again, appologies for my stupidity, but i feel there is a lack of guidence on the embedded API page.

*EDIT: i have replaced the .json path with that files physical location and tried to run it via the following cmd line:
C:\python27\python.exe C:\dev\python\<.json file name>
But it returns nothing.*

Comment: Don't try to execute the json file. Execute the service-account.py file. Also currently file just defines a method which returns the token you could have it print the results instead.

Comment: Any ideas what i would change where in the .py file to make it print the response?

Comment: Ok, printing the access token is no good as it expires after a short period.

Unless there is a way to generate an access token with a much much longer expiry date?

Comment: You could follow what they are doing in the [source code](https://github.com/googleanalytics/ga-dev-tools/blob/master/lib/service_account.py), In essence they create an API end point from which the browser client can request a new token whenever one is needed.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/googleanalytics/ga-dev-tools/blob/980ee19e0ddfb6f0e20ea9d836d373e937d005c1/lib/controllers/server_side_auth.py) is where the magic bit happens. The example uses django (python) and gets the token and then uses variable replacement in the page template.

Comment: I know that the .py collects the token, and i know that my script requires the token. But what im struggling with is how does the script know where to look for the token?

As i said, im running the script part via "embedded code" on sharepoint. I have the .py file stored on the server sharepoint is installed on. 

But i have no idea how the script from sharepoint is meant to retrieve the token and place it in the variable:

* Authorize the user with an access token obtained server side.
*/
gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
'serverAuth': {
'access_token': '{{ ACCESS_TOKEN_FROM_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}'

Comment: Forgive my stupidity, but im like a fish out of water when it comes to API's and/or Python

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how share point works and if you are able to pass variables to pages, but basically share point would need to call the python script collect the token and place it in the given JavaScript.

Comment: This i am fully aware of. But im at a loss on finding out exactly how this is done???